# Request count sql in symfony return boolean not integer

Tags: php, sql, symfony, doctrine-orm, dbal

in symfony I want to get count from table in database but it return boolean !

```js
    
    $sql = "....";
    $em = $this->getDoctrine()->getManager();
    $stmt = $em->getConnection()->prepare($sql);   
    $stmt->execute();


    $res = $stmt->fetchAll();
    foreach ($res as $key => $value) {
               $resultatRequete = "SELECT count(id) from inscriptions where seance_id = 
 '".$value['seance_id']."' and is_confirmed is not null";

                     $stmt2 = $em->getConnection()->prepare($resultatRequete);
                     $result_req = $stmt2->execute();
                     $res[$key]["count_inscrit"] = $result_req ;
    }
    return $res;
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The execute method return a boolean in order to success/failure, then you should fetch the result, as example:

```
                 // you can check on success ...
                 $success = $stmt2->execute();

                 $result_req = $stmt2->fetch();
                 $res[$key]["count_inscrit"] = $result_req ;
```

Hope this help

Comment: tha result is for example :        count_inscrit: {
count(id): "13"
}   how to make it count_inscri: "13"  !!

Comment: so the results is an array, so try to select as `SELECT count(id)  as count` then fetch as element as `$result_req['count']`